# Nested Form: "Cannot call create unless the parent is saved" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have a nested form where each post has and belongs to many locations. Adding locations to a post with the nested form works just fine. However when I click 'edit' and change anything except a location I get passed the `cannot call create unless the parent is saved` error.

I'm guessing this is something to do with the bit of code in my model which runs through the `location_attributes` being submitted and checks them for uniqueness however I have no idea how to fix this. I have tried just `@post.save!` before I do `find_or_initialize_by_name` in the controller but get the same error.

Code is below. I know this is pretty unique to me but any suggestions would be great!

**posts_controller.rb**

```
...
def update
   location_set = params[:post].delete(:locations_attributes) unless params[:post][:locations_attributes].blank?
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.locations = Location.find_or_initialize_location_set(location_set) unless location_set.nil?

  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Blog post was successfully updated.'
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end
...
```

**location.rb (model)**
    include PublicActivity::Model
    tracked
    tracked owner: Proc.new{ |controller, model| controller.current_user }

```
include FriendlyId
friendly_id :name

after_save { |location| location.destroy if location.name.blank? }
after_save { |venue| venue.destroy if venue.name.blank? }


has_many :location_post, :order => "position"
has_many :posts, :through => :location_post, :order => 'location_posts.position'


attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :name, :post_id, :notes, :asset, :assets_attributes, :venues_attributes
attr_accessor :_destroy, :position, :location_post_id


def self.find_or_initialize_location_set(location_set)
  #create a locations array
  locations = []

  locations = locations.delete_if { |elem| elem.flatten.empty? }
  location_set.each do |key, location|
    if location.delete(:_destroy) == "1"
      locations.delete_if {|elem| elem[:name] == location[:name]}
    else
  locations << find_or_initialize_by_name(location)  
  #REMINDER In rails 4 this must be written as where(...).first_or_create
    end
end
locations
end
```

**EDIT - The Error **

```
app/models/location.rb:10:in `block in <class:Location>'
app/controllers/blogit/posts_controller.rb:97:in `update'
```

Comment: Can you show the application line of code where the error actually happens?

Comment: Hi @moritz, It actually occurs on line `after_save { |venue| venue.destroy if venue.name.blank? }`. If I comment this out it fixes it. I can't believe it was that easy. *hits self in forehead*

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a stupid mistake.

The line `after_save { |venue| venue.destroy if venue.name.blank? }` is no longer relevant.

I'm an idiot and didn't read the error properly. Thanks for all those who helped.